# Woocommerce insert images attachments

Tags: php, wordpress

Im creating a product post (in wordpress) with all the necesary elements, everithing is fine: title, brand, reviews, for featured image i made this code:

```
$media_id = media_sideload_image($imgppal, $new_post_id, null, 'id');

set_post_thumbnail($new_post_id, $media_id);
```

Everything is fine until here, but I can´t insert more images to a product, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

A post can only have 1 thumbnail by default. If you want to add multiple images you can use the wp_insert_attachment() functionality to add multiple images.

```
<?php
$media_id = media_sideload_image($imgppal, $new_post_id, null, 'id');
$attachment = array(
    'ID' => $media_id,
    'post_parent' => $custom_post_id //post id you want to add the image to
);
wp_insert_attachment( $attachment );

?>
```

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance: $custom_post_id = $new_post_id ?